# Can't grant column specific privileges in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Going off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531456/654789) I am executing the below statements

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
   id      INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
GRANT SELECT ON person(id) TO SomeOne;
```

but when I do so, I get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(id) TO SomeOne' at line 1

Can someone shed some light as to why I am getting this error.

**MysQL version:**

> > mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.58, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GRANT SELECT (id) ON person TO SomeOne;
```

Check the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
GRANT select (`id`) ON your_db_name.your_table_name TO SomeOne
```

Comment: why do you have backquotes? Do they serve a particular purpose?