# Is there a method in MySQL to protect fields from changes?

Tags: mysql

We get this daily data feed. (We have no control over the original data, so asking them to correct the database isn't an option.)

The customer records contain addresses in the US. Street address, City, State and Zip.

On our end, we use the data in a database for the marketing department. They sometimes find the address is incorrect, or incomplete, and want to make changes to it. But of course, the next data feed would come in and wipe out their corrections.

Is there a method inf MySQL to protect certain fields from being changes, kind of like a protected cell in a spreadsheet. This is some of the field names of the MySQL record layout:

> address1
>  address2
>  address3
>  city
>  state
>  zipcode

What if I created along side of this, additional fields that are flagged either "Y" or "N" as being a protected field:

> address1
>  address1_flag
>  address2
>  address2_flag
>   address3
>  address3_flag
>  city
>  city_flag
>  state
>   state_flag
>  zipcode
>  zipcode_flag

So when the marketing department corrects, for example, the zipcode, it would set the zipcode_flag to "Y" meaning, Yes protect the field zipcode from further changes. If the original data feed does get corrected at a later point, then if zipcode from the marketing department's database matches the original field, then the zipcode_flag protection would be changed to "N".

Does this sound like the correct method to manage the marketing department's database from the daily feed? Or is there another approach or feature available in MySQL to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-lock-modes.html) will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a "protected" flag or feature, but there are a few roads you could take to accomplish your goal.

The first and most specific would be to create a "restricted user" in MySQL. To restrict the user, you can/would grant only `SELECT` privileges to the column(s) you don't want modified. To do this you would use:

```
GRANT SELECT(zipcode) ON addresses TO restrictedUser;
```

You can see a good example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531320/mysql-how-to-apply-grants-to-column), or get detailed information in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html).

A second method would be to create a procedure that selects/inserts/updates. This one may be overkill, but could be accomplished to suit your needs and won't require modifying user permissions.

A simple example of a select and update procedure would be (not tested):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_addresses ()
BEGIN 
   SELECT address1, zipcode FROM addresses;
END 

CREATE PROCEDURE update_addresses ( IN recordID INT(11), IN newAddress1 VARCHAR(255) )
BEGIN
    SET @query := CONCAT("UPDATE addresses SET address1 = '", newAddress1, "' WHERE id = ", recordId);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

This will allow a user to select any column you specify that they're allowed to read by calling `select_addresses()` and then perform an update on any allowed column via `update_addresses()`. You'd have to add several layers of logic to only update variables that have been set, etc - so using a procedure may in fact be overkill =P

Comment: So when an UPDATE is done by the restrictedUser they would only be allowed to update the other fields, but not the zipcode field? When the restrictedUser user attempts to UPDATE the zipcode field, does this generate an error condition in MySQL? I would be programming this in PHP, if that matters.

Comment: @Edward Correct, it would fail with an error. The error would be probably be an 'Access denied' error.

Comment: OK, so in PHP would there be a check to see if permission is denied so it doesn't generate an error? I would want the daily feed to be able to add new customer records, but not change the zipcode field (in this example). Thanks!

Comment: @Edward Yeah, you could actually. When there's an error you can always check the error-number returned to determine "what kind" of error it was. The exact error (for an `UPDATE`) will look like "ERROR 1143 (42000): UPDATE command denied to user ...". This means, the error-number will be `1143`. If you're using `mysqli`, you can get the number via `$mysqli->errno` (check [here](http://us2.php.net/mysqli_errno) for more info).

Answer (score 3):

You can manage privileges at the column-level:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to set a trigger that works off a flag in the records. For example if you had a field in the table

```
modified TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

THEN you create a Trigger to preserve the data

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `database_name`.`table_name_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `table_name` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.modified=1) THEN
/* Then set any fields you want to preserve to their old value */
SET NEW.address1=OLD.address1;
SET NEW.address2=OLD.address2;
SET NEW.city=OLD.city;
SET NEW.stateprov=OLD.stateprov;
SET NEW.postal_code=OLD.postal_code;
SET NEW.country=OLD.country;
END IF;
END
```

This would allow you to restrict modifications unless modified is set to 1. If you wanted to take it one step further and once modified prevent it from ever being modified, the modified flag could also be included so once set it couldn't change short of pulling the trigger from the db

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `database_name`.`table_name_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `table_name` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.modified=1) THEN
/* Then set any fields you want to preserve to their old value */
SET NEW.modified=OLD.modified;
SET NEW.address1=OLD.address1;
SET NEW.address2=OLD.address2;
SET NEW.city=OLD.city;
SET NEW.stateprov=OLD.stateprov;
SET NEW.postal_code=OLD.postal_code;
SET NEW.country=OLD.country;
END IF;
END
```